# Non-idempotent but safe transition in the REST architecture

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-architecture

Can you please provide an example of a RESTful API call (using HTTP protocol) which is non-idempotent and safe, at the same time (does something like that even exist)?

To elaborate a little bit on this, while reading about the [Hypermedia-Oriented Design](http://www.w3.org/2011/10/integration-workshop/p/hypermedia-oriented-design.pdf), I've encountered the 4 affordance aspects that describe each transition: safety, idempotence, mutability and transclusion. Also, I've encountered [a table](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/) which describes the HTTP verbs through those aspects and it goes like this:

```
---------------------------------
HTTP Method    Idempotent    Safe
---------------------------------
OPTIONS        yes           yes
GET            yes           yes
HEAD           yes           yes
PUT            yes           no
POST           no            no
DELETE         yes           no
PATCH          no            no
---------------------------------
```

My intuition tells me that all of the safe methods are automatically idempotent too (but not vice versa). I would just like to either confirm or refute this once and for all.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: I wish the word immutable or read-only was used instead of "safe".

Comment: @AdamGent I agree that would be clearer. I think "safe" is used to avoid confusion with the client-side mutability concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A safe method - one that does not modify anything - is by definition idempotent. Since it has not changed anything, it will have the same effect (that is, no effect whatsoever) no matter how many times you call it.

Comment: No because if you check the doc he pointed to safe just means read only. So something that returns say a time stamp would be safe but not idempotent.

Comment: A read-only method that returns a time stamp wouldn't be RESTful according to this doc. You would use GET for that, which must be implemented as both safe and idempotent.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say and would like to add something to it. Safe does indeed mean read-only access, which is idempotent by itself, since it doesn't change the resource on each and every request, thus produces the same potency/effect (does nothing to a resource, every time).

Comment: Regarding the GET endpoint for timer, I believe it is both safe and idempotent, because with each request, we don't change the time returned, we are only reading it. It's like we are doing multiple GET requests to a resource which someone else is constantly changing with PUT/PATCH requests. GET request is obviously safe and idempotent (since it doesn't change the resource in any way). The fact the resource is changing, is the result of something else influencing that change, which is not our GET request. So, the endpoint is still RESTfull and our GET request is still safe and idempotent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All safe methods are also idempotent, but they refer to two different (but related) qualities of a RESTful API.

A safe method call (one which does not modify the state of the resource on the server) may be issued multiple times by the client without affecting the state of the server (the definition of idempotency).